# Upgrading NewtonSoft causes 404 error (0x80070002)

Tags: c#, json.net

.Net 4.6.1 framework
I've Upgraded NewtonSoft in all my projects from 9.0.1 to 12.0.3.

Before the upgrade everything works fine -
Now I got in my home page:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      https://www.example.com:443/home/index
Physical Path      C:\path\to\home\index
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: I don't see any way it can possibly cause a 404 result because it's a later step in the pipeline. Indeed, the handler is the "static file" handler, rather than a controller.

Comment: Thanks @John for responding - could you a bit explain that? or direct me to relevant resources?
once I downgrade back to newtonSoft 9 all starts to work again.

Comment: It looks like it's a problem with routing, because it's hitting the static file handler (i.e. it's expecting that `/home/index` is a physical file). Without seeing your configuration, etc. it's difficult to provide more advice.

Comment: `Handler StaticFile` isn't what I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, After I debug the global.asax I found there was an exception been thrown.

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

So I understand my web.config still looks for NewtonSoft 9.

Changing in the web.config from this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

to this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Solved the issue for me.